# How run servo and ultrasonic sensor concurently with millis on arduino?

Tags: arduino, multitasking, timedelay

I have a problem with the servo and ultrasonic that can not run concurently. My code works at the moment as follow : servo will move every 10 seconds and ultrasonic always detect the range and display the result on LED.
I was looking for references on google and I found out that the delay caused servo and ultrasonic can't run together. multitasking required in order to use the millis (). but I still can not use the function millis ().
how to change the delay in my code with millis()?

Thanks for helping me!

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
#define ledM 10
#define ledK 9
#define ledH 8

Servo ikiservo;  //servo 
int pos = 0;    //set positon servo
int pinSpeaker = 4;  //buzzer

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600); //SERIAL
  ikiservo.attach(3); //servo
  pinMode(pinSpeaker, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); //ultrasonic
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); //ultrasonic
  pinMode(ledM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledH, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //-------------SERVO----------

  for(pos = 0; pos < 90; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 90 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of  1 degree 
    ikiservo.write(pos);            
    delay(10000);       // waits 10s for the servo to reach the position 
  }

  //---------ULTRASONIC-----------
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm");
  delay (400);

  if (distance > 4 && distance <7) {  // turn on ledM when distance 4<distance<7
    digitalWrite(ledM,HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(ledK,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledH,LOW);
    playTone(300, 160);          //buzzer ON
    delay(1000);
    //buzzer
  } else if(distance > 2 && distance <4) {// turn on ledK when 7<distance<4
    digitalWrite(ledM,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledK,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledH,LOW);
    playTone(0, 0);
    delay(1000);
  } else if(distance <2) {//turn on ledH when distance<2
    digitalWrite(ledM,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledK,LOW); 
    digitalWrite(ledH,HIGH);
    playTone(0, 0);
    delay(1000);
  } else{                      //turn off all
    digitalWrite(ledM,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledK,LOW);  
    digitalWrite(ledH,LOW);
    playTone(0, 0);
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void playTone(long duration, int freq) { //funtion for add tone on buzzer
    duration *= 1000;
    int period = (1.0 / freq) * 1000000;
    long elapsed_time = 0;
    while (elapsed_time < duration) {
        digitalWrite(pinSpeaker,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
        digitalWrite(pinSpeaker, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
        elapsed_time += (period);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not waiting for 10 seconds, but for 15 minutes. Probably that one is the only issue in your code.

Just write this

```
for(pos = 0; pos < 90; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 90 degrees 
{                                 // in steps of  1 degree 
    ikiservo.write(pos);            
    delay(100); // waits 0.1s for the servo to reach the position
                // so total time will be 9 seconds
}
```

If, on the other way, you want to span the 90° area in 10 seconds, then go back, the code is

```
void loop() {
    //-------------SERVO----------

    for(pos = 0; pos < 90; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 90 degrees 
    {                                  // in steps of  1 degree 
        ikiservo.write(pos);

        //---------ULTRASONIC-----------
        long duration, distance;
        digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
        delayMicroseconds(2);
        digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
        duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
        distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
        Serial.print(distance);
        Serial.println(" cm");

        if (distance > 4 && distance <7) {  // turn on ledM when distance 4<distance<7
            digitalWrite(ledM,HIGH); 
            digitalWrite(ledK,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledH,LOW);
        } else if(distance > 2 && distance <4) {// turn on ledK when 7<distance<4
            digitalWrite(ledM,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledK,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(ledH,LOW);
        } else if(distance <2) {//turn on ledH when distance<2
            digitalWrite(ledM,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledK,LOW); 
            digitalWrite(ledH,HIGH);
        } else{                      //turn off all
            digitalWrite(ledM,LOW);
            digitalWrite(ledK,LOW);  
            digitalWrite(ledH,LOW);
        }

        delay(100); // waits 0.1s for the servo to reach the position 
    }
}
```

I had to remove the tone, because the way you use it does not allow other "processes" to work concurrently. Just see if it is the approach you want;if it is report back and we can see how to implement it also with the buzzer

Comment: maybe tone needs to be removed. I'm still confused how to make the buzzer can be run concurrently as well. but thanks for your help. servo and ultrasonic can be run concurrently..

Comment: Try using the `tone` function (see [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone)). I hope it is non-blocking